# nest : how do an index mapping by passing a raw request?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I would like to do an index mapping by passing through nest but by i want to   give directly a raw elasticsearch request:

```
var setting = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("uri"));
setting.DefaultIndex(_esIndexName);
var client = new ElasticClient(setting);

string rawEsRequest= "PUT /myindex
{
   ""mappings"": {
      ""review"": {
        ""properties"": {
          ""commentaire"": {
            ""analyzer"" : ""french"",
            ""type"": ""text"",
            ""fields"": {
              ""keyword"": {
                ""type"": ""keyword"",
                ""ignore_above"": 256
              }
            }
          },
          ""date_creaation"": {
            ""type": "date""
          }
}}}}"

//want to do this bellow
client.Mapping.rawPut(rawEsRequest);
```

Do you know if it is possible to give a direct elasticsearch request for doing mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with the low level client in `Elasticsearch.Net` that is also exposed on the high level client in NEST through the `.LowLevel` property. You just need to remove the HTTP verb and URI as these are part of the method call on the client.

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var defaultIndex = "myindex;
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

string rawEsRequest = @"{
    ""mappings"": {
        ""review"": {
            ""properties"": {
                ""commentaire"": {
                    ""analyzer"" : ""french"",
        ""type"": ""text"",
        ""fields"": {
                        ""keyword"": {
                            ""type"": ""keyword"",
            ""ignore_above"": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
              ""date_creaation"": {
                            ""type"": ""date""
              }
            }
        }
    }
}";

ElasticsearchResponse<dynamic> putResponse = 
    client.LowLevel.IndicesCreate<dynamic>(defaultIndex, rawEsRequest);
```